# Multiple woocommerce custom order checkout fields

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

so, I'm stuck with adding second custom checkout field to my store.

That first custom field is radio buttons and it is added straight in to template field. The other one is the same radio buttons but with different id and names.

Shipping part works just fine, but that **Private label** is not saving and is not displayed in admin area after order is complete.

**Here is what I already have, what am i doing wrong?**

```
/**
 * Update the user meta with field value
 **/
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_user_meta', 'my_custom_checkout_field_update_user_meta');
function my_custom_checkout_field_update_user_meta( $user_id ) {
    if ($user_id && $_POST['shippinng']) update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shippinng', esc_attr($_POST['shippinng']) );
    if ($user_id && $_POST['private']) update_user_meta( $user_id, 'private', esc_attr($_POST['private']) );
}


/**
 * Update the order meta with field value
 **/
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta');

function my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
    if ($_POST['shippinng']) update_post_meta( $order_id, 'Transport', esc_attr($_POST['shippinng']));
    if ($_POST['private']) update_post_meta( $order_id, 'Private label', esc_attr($_POST['private']));
}


/**
 * Display field value on the order edit page
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta', 10, 1 );

function my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta($order){
    echo '<p><strong>'.__('Transport').':</strong> ' . get_post_meta( $order->id, 'Transport', true ) . '</p>';
    echo '<p><strong>'.__('Private label').':</strong> ' . get_post_meta( $order->id, 'Private label', true ) . '</p>';
}


/**
 * Add the field to order emails
 **/
add_filter('woocommerce_email_order_meta_keys', 'my_custom_checkout_field_order_meta_keys');
function my_custom_checkout_field_order_meta_keys( $keys ) {
    $keys[] = 'Transport';
    $keys[] = 'Private label';
    return $keys;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to register private label in order to save it. I advise downloading checkout field editor and examining the code for learning purposes. Comparison has always been a good model to follow from my experience :)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a full answer but I can see one issue with how you are adding the fields to the emails. It's an old question but I thought I'd answer it to help myself out when I inevitably have to Google it in 6 months.

Doing this:

```
$keys[] = 'Transport';
$keys[] = 'Private label';
```

The second line overwrites the first, so the $keys array becomes just `array( "Private label" );`.

Instead, try formatting it like this:

```
$keys = array("Transport", "Private label");
```

This is working on my current project:

```
/* Add custom field to emails */
add_filter('woocommerce_email_order_meta_keys', 'my_custom_order_meta_keys');

function my_custom_order_meta_keys( $keys ) {
     $keys = array("Purchase Order Number", "Preferred Delivery Date"); // This will look for both of the specified fields and add them to the emails
     return $keys;
}
```